# Converting units when $c=G=1$

Tags: dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion, absolute-units

In my homework assignment it is written that to convert from time to length you need to multiply by $c$, and to convert from mass to length you need to multiply by $G/c^2$, however I dont entirely understand why it is true. Is there a way to quickly see what coefficients need to be added? Some calculation so I can reconstruct it without looking at a conversion table?

Comment: Do you know how to use dimensional analysis?

Comment: I.e. you are *totally cool* with  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Definition)?

Comment: I know how to convert between g to kg, m to km, never before I used units where c=G=1, can you show an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way: Although $c=1$ the standard relation $c = s/t$ still holds. Hence, $s = c * t$.

The dimension of the gravitational constant  is given by $[G]= [F/m \cdot r^2]  = m^3 / (kg \, s^2)$. Solving for "length" we obtain $m = kg\,s^2/m^2 \cdot [G] = kg \; [G/c^2]$.

Hence, you always take the original definition of the constants and solve for the appropriate unit.

Comment: Thank you very much